# How can I solve twitter-bootstrap error from ROR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

Hello Can anybody help me to resolve this following error from Ruby on Rails.

## Error:

```
C:/Site/bootstrap/config/application.rb:13:in `<module:Bootstrap>': uninitialize
d constant Bootstrap::Rails::Application (NameError)
```

I have added "gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1.1'" in my gem file and run bundle install.When i typed command rails g controller users,It gave me the above error.I am using rails version 3.2.19 and ruby version 1.9.3.My gem file is as follows.

## Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.19'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1.1'
```

## config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Bootstrap
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename your application from `Bootstrap` to something else as it's conflict with `bootstrap-sass` gem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in your project name... Unfortunately, because your application is called Bootstrap (you can see that in your config/application.rb in line 12, where module Bootstrap is defined), and in the gem source, another module Bootstrap is created (check here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/lib/bootstrap-sass.rb#L2). This probably makes problem for Ruby.

Try to generate new rails app, but give it different name, like

`rails new bootstrap_playground`

There should not be any problem with name collisions.

Hope that helps!